# Insert statement for mysql and oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

My application can work with both mySql and Oracle db. I've a requirement to add current time in one column( data type :date ) of a transaction table. Oracle has sysdate function but mySql doesnt and mysql has now() function but oracle doesnt.

Is there a way to create single insert statement which will work with both mysql and oracle ?

Comment: These databases both support SQL in the vaguest sense, but anything non-trivial has platform-specific ways of expressing it. Your application will need to know how to write the correct query in more complicated cases than this where there won't be a single solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both Oracle and MySQL support `current_date`:

```
select current_date
```

If you want the time component as well as the date, use `current_timestamp`:

```
select current_timestamp
```